# How to implement notifications with firebase functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am coding in SwiftUI and have made a social media app.

Lets say User 1 messages User 2 - User 2 should get a notification from firebase saying that User 1 messaged u.

I want to make a firebase function that will use cloud messaging to send a notification to a specific user, as I explained earlier. I have basically implemented getting the document data.

This is what I have written so far -

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore.document('/messages/{uid}/{chatPartnerId}/{messageId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const message = snap.data();
    functions.logger.log(message);
    var uid = context.params.uid;
    
    admin.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)
    .then(function(token) {
        var currentUid = token;
    });
    
    var messageCollecRef = admin.firestore().collection('messages/' + uid + chatPartnerId + messageId);
    functions.logger.log(messageCollecRef_ForCurrentUser);
    
    return messageCollecRef.get().then(querySnapshot => {
        var tokens = [];
            tokens.push(doc.data().toId);
            functions.logger.log(toId);
        });
        
        const payload = {
            "notification": {
                "title": message.title,
                "body": message.title,
                "sound": "default"
            },
            "data": {
                "sendername": message.title,
                "message": message.title
            }
        }
        
        functions.logger.log(payload);
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload)
    });
    
});
```

this is my firebase structure -
messages | uid | chatPartnerId | message id |

If u need anything else, please let me know in the comments. Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking for someone to write it for you? What have you tried for the rest of the implementation? What does the documentation say about this? What specific part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @loremipsum there was a part of the code missing actually, mb sorry! I am having trouble sending the notification to the user. I have made the edits in my question and typed out my firebase structure. Please check the missing code i uploaded.

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared? Specifically: when you step through this code in a debugger line by line, and check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?